# How to i print the value of i?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How to i print the value of i ?

In this code it print like this:

1.i
2.i
3.i
4.i
5.i

```
var i;

$("#btn2").click(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $("ol").prepend("<li>i</li>");
    }
});
```

Comment: @huydq5000 I think just putting the `"<li>" + i + </li>"` would've been enough for a comment :)

Comment: Ha ha, I have to remove the comment because it's messy.

Comment: @George Or just `\`<li>${i}</li>\``. Or a safer approacher `$("<li>").text(i).prependTo("ol")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        $("ol").prepend("<li>"+i+"</li>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    $("ol").prepend("<li>" + i + "</li>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        $("ol").prepend("<li>" + i + ".i</li>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is variable i is used as string and not variable. You need to concatenate variable correctly:

```
"<li>"+i+"</li>"
```

However, Using append or prepend in for loop is not a good practice, the method of creating one really long string and appending it at the end will be the best choice, as it makes the best use of the trade offs of code legibility, ease of programming, and speed. something like this:

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
 var dataForPrepend = [];
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
    dataForPrepend.push("<li>"+i+"</li>");
 }
 $("ol").prepend(dataForPrepend.join(''));
});
```

Ill also suggest you to have a look at **[reasons-to-use-append-prepend-correctly](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly)**